# Using Database First - Entity, I want my database in App_data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, entity-framework-6

I would like a web applications MVC 5 using the Entity Framework on the local IIS server and Azure. Also, two publication.

When publishing to IIS (FileSystem), the application is displayed but there is no interaction with the database.

I created a project using Database First (ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> EF Designer from Databes)

Context has generated

```
public PriceProductsDBEntities ()
            : Base ( "name = PriceProductsDBEntities")
        {
        }
```

as well as the connection string in webconfig.

```
<Add name = "PriceProductsDBEntities" connectionString = "metadata =
res: //*/ProduktModel.csdl | res: //*/ProduktModel.ssdl | res:
//*/ProduktModel.msl; provider = System.Data.SqlClient; provider
connection string = & quot; data source = MICHAL \ SQLEXPRESS; initial
catalog = PriceProductsDB; Integrated Security = True;
MultipleActiveResultSets = True; app = EntityFramework & quot; "
providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Im googling and a lot of people suggested adding a connection parameter AttachDBFilename = | DataDirectory | PriceProductsDB.mdf unfortunately the build folder App_Data remained empty even after pressing the "Show all files".

I tried manually copy database to **App_data** then after pressing the "Show all files" appeared to me and pressed Include in project but it was two other connections.

My guess is that you have to somehow convert connectingString generated by the entity that added to the **App_Data** folder, and then publish to IIS and applications would interact with the database.

As for the Azure versions have a trial (free) for publication. I published on Azure your application and it is the same situation for the IIS. But the application displays no interaction with the database.

Comment: If you copy the mdf file in app_data folder, is it working fine on local machine? Are you using the same connection string when you publish the site to the Azure? How many instances of web servers you are using on Azure ?

Comment: No, just added another connection. Yes, i using this same connection in Azure. Just one namepc\SQLEXPRESS. I already have on IIS website with database.

Comment: I got Error communicate: Cannot open Database "PriceProductsDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' then i change on IIS Manager => Application Pools => DefaultAppPool ==> LocalService. When i changed i gotted another error: Cannot open Database "PriceProductsDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'ZARZĄDZANIE NT\USŁUGA LOKALNA'

Comment: then i open SSMS ==> connect pcname\SQLEXPRESS ==> Security ==> Users ==> New login ==> login name: ZARZĄDZANIE NT\USŁUGA LOKALNA ==> add ==> right click to ZARZĄDZANIE NT\USŁUGA LOKALNA ==> properties ==> User Mapping ==> Users mapped to this login ==> check my database ==> User ZARZĄDZANIE NT\USŁUGA LOKALNA ==> Default Schema ==> db_owner ==> Database role membership for my database => check db_owner and public and then my application with database working. (Using SQL Server 2016).

Comment: But still i got problem with Azure.

Comment: One thing you need to understand it that server names on your local machine and azure machine are different.  So the same connection string won't work on azure.  Also you need to make sure  that the Azure machine has SQL Express installed on it and with proper users having access to it so that you won't get login failed error.

Comment: When i want interaction to my database on Azure i got this error communicate: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Your local application connects to local sql server. If you are using the same connection string in azure that means azure machine tries to connect to your local sql server and it's not able to connect it. That's why you are seeing this error. Consider using azure sql server instead of sql express.

Comment: You're right, I know how to create a base in Azure. Only one thing puzzles me, if I have an application with a database fired on IIS and that I also have the same application with the same database on Azure? and then it will be a conflict of calls?

Comment: That depends on development process you follow. You can connect to azure db directly from local IIS application. Or you use local db for local application and azure db for azure deployed application. In that case you need to make sure to transform connection string value when you deploy on azure.